# Como fazer um lookbehind utilizando quantificadores como o "\d+"?

Tags: regex

Preciso dar *match* no texto "teste", porém nem sempre a string começará com um numero fixo de caracteres/digitos, pode ser que ela comece com qualquer numero de caracteres, exemplo:

001  **teste**
0002  **teste**
20458  **teste**

Como faço para que a regexp abaixo funcione?

```
(?<=^\d+)teste
```

Esse *lookbehind* `(?<=^\d+)` não funciona, dá expressão inválida, não deixa usar o quantificador `\d+` dentro do *lookbehind*, se eu fizer `(?<=^\d\d\d)` ele dá *match* somente na primeira situação. Eu gostaria que ele pudesse ser "variável" o número de dígitos/caracteres antes do texto do *match*.

Existe como criar um *lookbehind* usando quantificadores `+`, `*` ou `{1,}`?

Comment: Qual linguagem, se não me engano javascript não tem lookbehind;;;

Comment: De fato, os operadores de fecho são inválidos em _lookbehind_.

Comment: não acho que seja JS, na própria pergunta ele afirma que o lookbehind funcionou ao mudar o \d+

Comment: Linguagem JAVA / C#, em javascript estou ciente de que não existe lookbehind.

Comment: Sei que faz tempo que essa pergunta foi feita, mas enfim, acho que vale a pena atualizar: agora é possível em Java e JavaScript (em C# já era possível também). Deixei [uma resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/576001/112052) abaixo detalhando melhor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Existe como criar um lookbehind usando quantificadores `+`, `*` ou `{1,}`?*

Dependendo da *engine*/linguagem/ferramenta utilizada, pode ou não ser possível.

Em PHP e Python, por exemplo - pelo menos nas versões atuais - não é possível, inclusive expressões que contém quantificadores dentro de um *lookbehind* dão erro.

> Obs: em Python, você pode usar o [módulo `regex`](https://pypi.org/project/regex/). Com ele, é possível usar quaisquer quantificadores no *lookbehind*:
>
> ```py
> # módulo externo, instalar com "pip install regex"
> # https://pypi.org/project/regex/
> import regex as re
>
> r = re.compile(r'(?<=^\d+)teste', re.M)
> print(r.findall('001teste\n0002teste\n20458teste\nabcdef')) # ['teste', 'teste', 'teste']
> ```
>
> Inclusive, isto está descrito na [documentação](https://pypi.org/project/regex/#variable-length-lookbehind): "*A lookbehind can match a variable-length string*".

Em outros casos é parcialmente possível. Por exemplo, nas versões mais antigas do Java, você podia usar `?` (que indica algo opcional), ou quantificadores fixos (como `{1,5}`), desde que tivesse o valor máximo especificado.
Porém, **nas versões mais recentes**, não existem mais estas restrições (se não me engano, desde a versão 13), e agora isso é perfeitamente possível:

```java
String s = "001teste\n0002teste\n20458teste\n fasdfsadfasd";
// nas versões mais recentes do Java, isso é permitido
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?<=^\\d+)teste", Pattern.MULTILINE).matcher(s);
while (m.find()) { // imprime "teste" 3 vezes
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

E nas versões mais recentes do JavaScript, também é possível (testado no Chrome e Firefox mais recentes):

```js
const regex = /(?<=^\d+)teste/mg;
const s = '001teste\n0002teste\n20458teste\nabcdef';
console.log(s.match(regex)); // [ 'teste', 'teste', 'teste' ]
```

E em C#, já faz tempo que isso é possível (inclusive, se não me engano, na época em que esta pergunta foi feita):

```cs
var matches = Regex.Matches("001teste\n0002teste\n20458teste\nabcdef", @"(?<=^\d+)teste",
                            RegexOptions.Multiline);
foreach (Match match in matches)
{ // imprime "teste" 3 vezes
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
}
```

Portanto, [a resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/207746/112052) que diz não dá para fazer não está mais correta (talvez estivesse na época, pois muitas linguagens que hoje implementam, o fizeram em versões posteriores).

Para saber os motivos pelos quais muitas linguagens não implementavam este recurso, só perguntando para quem tomou tais decisões. Meu palpite é que a dificuldade de implementação e/ou os custos no desempenho da regex acabavam não compensando. Afinal, tanto *lookaheads* quanto *lookbehinds* já são custosos por si só, pois você tem que avançar ou retroceder na string e depois voltar onde estava para continuar procurando os *matches*. E um quantificador como `*` ou `+` (sem limite superior) faz com que você tenha que voltar uma quantidade indeterminada de caracteres, tornando tudo mais custoso ainda (algumas *engines* "resolvem" isso invertendo a regex e fazendo a busca da direita para a esquerda; apesar de ser menos custoso, ainda sim não é uma implementação tão trivial, principalmente se começarmos a incluir outros *lookarounds* dentro do *lookbehind*).

Apesar desses poréns, várias *engines* decidiram implementar mesmo assim (o que mudou? só perguntando para quem decidiu incluir este recurso).

De qualquer forma, na época da pergunta isso podia não ser possível na maioria dos casos. Mas hoje, dependendo da linguagem e/ou versão e/ou bibliotecas que você usa, pode ser possível sim (ver também [este artigo](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#limitbehind) para mais detalhes).

Comment: Muito bom! perfeita e completa resposta.

Answer (score 7):

Em vez de usar *lookbehind*, você está mais bem servido usando um grupo de captura para obter uma referência à sequência `test`:

```
/^\d+(test)/
```

Aí você acessa o grupo 1 para obter a string `test`. Tudo bem que é meio inútil, se tratando de uma *string* fixa, mas o conceito é o mesmo quando se quer extrair parte de uma sequência de caracteres.

Answer (score 3):

A Resposta do [@Wtrmute](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/207300/14213) esta de acordo com sua necessidade, mas vamos focar em sua duvida.

> Como fazer um look-behind utilizando quantificadores?

#### Resposta

**Você não faz**, o look-behind teria a logica de que **você sabe o que vem antes** da sua real captura.
E um quantificador quebra essa regra, pois se você usa um quantificador é justamente porque você não sabe ao certo quantas vezes "algo" deve ocorrer.

#### Adendo

Você deve lembrar que o *look-behind* ao certo trabalha de traz para frente.

Ele primeiramente vai procurar por `teste` apos ele "anda pra traz" verificando o *look-behind*.

```
0002 teste
   ^^|---| captura
   ||- 1ª verificação do look-behind
   |- 2ª verificação do look-behind
```

Comment: Entendo, bom, eu vou marcar esta resposta como aceita, já que infelizmente não tem como criar uma regex com look-behind dinâmico com quantificadores e o que eu quero fazer não é possível.

Answer (score 2):

RegEx sem *lookbehind* (lembrando que assim você precisa acessar o grupo1 pra obter somente "teste".)

```
\d*? (teste)
```

Usando *lookbehind* (esse lookbehind identifica o uso de 1 digito e espaço antes da palavra "teste", assim capturaria independente do número de dígitos.)

```
(?<=\d\s)teste
```

Comment: Eu acho que fui infeliz em formular a pergunta, não consegui explicar direito o que precisava, no meu exemplo eu tenho apenas digitos antes da string "teste", entretanto, há ocorrencias de qualquer caractere, e as vezes frases inteiras antes do meu objetivo final, mas andei lendo e acho que realmente nao tem como usar quantificador em look behind, infelizmente.

Comment: Depende do flavour da regex, onde está usando ela? Posso ajustar minha resposta para se adaptar a sua necessidade

Comment: @ThiagoHencke .\s(teste) resolve? o . significa qualquer caracter que não for uma quebra de linha, o \s indica espaço antes de teste, aí o () captura o que está entre ele se corresponder